# SOAP WSDL mis-configuration SOAP instead of SOAPENV

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl file containing a request configuration like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bscs="http://www.website.com/ws/bscs">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bscs:MyAction>
         <param1>?</param1>
         <param2>?</param2>
      </bscs:MyAction>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but when checking the logs of the webserver the soap request is sent in this way:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns3:MyAction xmlns:ns2="http://www.website.com/ws" xmlns:ns3="http://www.website.com/ws/bscs">
            <param1>20045454545</param1>
            <param2>45454</param2>
        </ns3:MyAction>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Do you have an idea on what might be causing the problem?

The scenario is that we have SOAP service integrated within a properiatry system (sys1). Now we want that service to be hosted in another system (sys2) and keep the communication between the sys1 and hosted service as usual.

Comment: Are you working on the service or the client? Is the request failing?

Comment: yes the request is failing and I please check the edit to see where exactly I am working

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with either of those.  The first one specifies that the namespace will be `soapenv`:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:**soapenv**="http://...
```

The second one specifies that the namespace will be `soap`:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:**soap=**"http://schemas...
```

This is normal [XML namespace behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).  Namespaces are aliases: it doesn't matter what they're called, it just matters how they're defined, which is described in the URL provided when they're declared.  In this case, both namespaces are defined by `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`, so they're the same thing.

It's entirely up to the message creator what they call their namespace.

Comment: the thing is that the definition of the service is done within the WSDL file in the first format whereas in the logs of the service that we are calling, the format of the request is in the second way. Something that is causing the request to fail.

Comment: Best guess is that whatever you're using to parse your SOAP message isn't a proper namespace-aware XML parser.  Have you written a custom "parser" that expects the message with the "soapenv" namespace?  If you have, you should change it to handle any namesspace.  Both messages are (in SOAP and XML terms) identical; it's not legitimate to accept one and not the other.